# C# - Await and async

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, parse-platform

Just want to make sure I get this correctly as I am seeing some weird behaviour based on my results.

I have defined an async method as follows:

```
public async Task<System.Net.HttpStatusCode> GetJson(Stream inputJson)
{
  ......
  .....
  ...
  var query1 = from xxx in new xxx()
               where xxx.id == myID
               select xxx;
  var results1 = await query1.FindAsync();

  var query2 = from yyy in new yyy()
               where yyy.id == myID
               select yyy;
  var results2 = await query2.FindAsync();
  ...
  ....
  .....
  return System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
}
```

Will `query2` execute only after `query1` finishes execution? Or in parallel?

Comment: `query2` will execute after `query1` yields a result.

Comment: @Polis: A good mental shortcut is: `await` means "asynchronous wait", so it *does* wait. It just waits asynchronously instead of blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code after await is constructed as so-called continuation. Critical part is this line:

```
var results1 = await query1.FindAsync();
```

`FindAsync` constructs a `Task` and then `await` indicates that the rest should be the continuation of that task.

That means that the rest of the method will be another `Task`, and that task would only execute after the first one completes. Even more, if the first task throws an exception, the second would not even be started.

So, the answer to your question is: Yes, `query2` will always execute after `query1` is complete.

Comment: thank  you. out of curiosity, if pretty much most of the code in an async method is marked with await, doesn't it beat the asynchronous aspect? I mean you might as well run everything synchronously, right? I am implying a non UI related process by the way.

Comment: Try to view that from the CPU point of view. Operations that are not entirely CPU bound, like database or network operations, will return control over the thread on which they are executing. That will let the task manager run other tasks on the same thread, which increases overall CPU utilization. Doing all of that synchronously will yield lower CPU utilization because current thread will be blocked and another thread would have to be started for other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `query1` will start and the method will suspend execution until `query1` completes. Only then the `query2` starts. If you want to execute them in parallel look into `Task.WhenAll(...)` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160384(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes `query2` will be executed after `await query1.FindAsync()` will return result. But be care on which thread it will continue. It depends.

If you want to do it concurrently you can use `Task.WhenAll` method. 
Example:

```
var firstTask = FirstMethodAsync();
var secondTask = SecondMethodAsync();
await Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask); 
// Here you can pull out Results from firstTask and secondTask.
var firstResult = firstTask.Result;
var secondResult = secondTask.Result;
```

More info about WhenAll method(s) you can found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.